# Show value in a field from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a input field that is readonly that shows the user the money they have left over after spending. They first have to enter their income and in the spending field, it will show the value from the database. My problem is after calculating the money left over in javascript, the value does not show in the leftOver field. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#addRecord").hide();
                 $("#btnAdd").click(function(){
                     $("#addRecord").show();
                 });
             });
         </script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
             function getTotalIncome(){
             var income = parseFloat(document.getElementById("income").value);
             var otherIncome = parseFloat(document.getElementById("otherIncome").value);
             var totalIncome = income + otherIncome;

             document.getElementById("totalIncome").value = '$' + totalIncome;
         }
         </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
                 function getLeftOver(){
                     var totalIncome = parseFloat(document.getElementById("totalIncome").value);
                     var totalSpending = parseFloat(document.getElementById("totalSpending").value);
                     var leftOver = totalIncome - totalSpending;

                     document.getElementById("leftOver").value = '$' + leftOver;
                 }
             </script>
        </head>
        <body>
             <button id="btnAdd" type="button" name="btnAdd">Create A Budget</button>

             <form id="addRecord" name="addRecord" action="Budget" method="post">
                 <h3>Income</h3>
                 <label>Income:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="income" id="income" onchange="getTotalIncome()"> <br>
                 <label>Other Income:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="otherIncome" id="otherIncome" onchange="getTotalIncome()"><br>

                 <hr>
                 <h3>Spending</h3>
                 <label>Total Amount Of Spending</label>
                 <input type="text" name="totalSpending" value="$${totalSpending}" disabled=disabled>

                 <hr>
                 <h4>You've budgeted</h4>
                 <label>Income</label>
                 <input type="text" name="totalIncome" id="totalIncome" readonly="readonly" onchange="getLeftOver()">
                 <label>Spending</label>
                 <input type="text" name="totalSpending" id="totalSpending" value="$${totalSpending}" readonly="readonly"  onchange="getLeftOver()">
                 <label>Left Over</label>
                 <input type="text" name="leftOver" id="leftOver" readonly="readonly">


            </form>
        </body>
```

Comment: In my opinion this is nothing that should be done via javascript as it can be manipulated

Comment: So should I send all the information to the servlet, calculate everything, store in the database, and then send it back to the jsp page

Comment: You should do the crucial calculation just on your server and use JS just to show your data but not to change it